# How to use dependent in Ruby-on-Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, dependent: :restrict_with_exception
end
```

users_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
...
  def destroy
    @user.destroy   
    flash[:danger] = "Success"
    redirect_to users_path
  rescue => e
    flash[:danger] = "Error"
    redirect_to @user
  end
...
end
```

**Why does it not catch an exception?**

Comment: Because there is not post record associated

Comment: what?????????????????????